# How to find Kubernets secrets values

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

What could be the `kubectl` command to see `k8s` `secret` values

I tried

```
kubectl get secrets/<secrets-name> -n <namespace>
```

It returns

```
NAME            TYPE     DATA   AGE
secrets1        Opaque   1      18h
```

but I want to know what value stored inside the secret

Answer (score 2):

Say you had a secret like the one below with a password key then something like this should work to obtain the value:

`kubectl get secret/my-secret -n dev -o go-template='{{.data.password|base64decode}}'`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata: 
  name: my-secret
  namespace: dev
type: Opaque
data: 
  password: TXEyRCMoOGdmMDk=
  username: cm9vdA==
```

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was so simple I just have to add  `-o jsonpath='{.data}'` at the end of the command

```
kubectl get secrets/<secrets-name> -n <namespace>  -o jsonpath='{.data}'
```

Comment: that would work too. I was missing a dash between go and template on initial post. Works now.

Comment: would be nice if you update your answer @Alan

Comment: Already done. Thanks!